# linked list : how to delete last node, where we have pointer to last node in a single linked list

Tags: c, linux, data-structures, linked-list

In a single linked list, we can delete a node with holding pointer to it.
This can be achieved by copying next node data into current node until we reach end.

But, How can we delete last node by holding and knowing pointer to self ?

-Thanks

Comment: You also need the address of the node before the last node. This node should have it's `next` pointer set to `NULL`. If you do not have access to the `head` node then the deletion is not possible.

Comment: I agree with you.
I came across of this question in interview with Qualcomm.
Interviewer is claiming that we can do this.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally not possible. You need the address of the node before the last node. This node should have it's `next` pointer set to `NULL`. The node before last cannot be directly accessed from the last node in a singly linked list.

However, if you have access to the `head` node, you can traverse the list again to get the node before the last node.

Answer (score 0):

when we delete the node, it means we free the memory pointed by the pointer not the pointer itself. Hence, Same can be done in last node case.

i.e.
 ptr=addressof(last node),which is not equal to address of the pointer.

Comment: In single linked list, last node must point to NULL.

Here real challenge is to set NULL into last but one node in single linked list.

struct node {
            int data;
            struct node *link;
x->y->z

let say x,y,z are 3 nodes in single linked list.

ptr is pointing to Z node.
Before deleting ptr, we need to set NULL in node "Y".